# Longitud dinámica de array en c++

Tags: c++

Estaba haciendo un programa que te pida la longitud de un array pero directamente el programa ni se inicia, si en vez de usar la variable longitud pongo directamente el numero el programa se inicia sin problemas, no se que puede estar pasando :(

Edit: si defino la variable **longitud** y pongo "new int[10]", en vez de ser de 10 será de **longitud**, cuando lo pruebo en repl.it funciona poniendo [longitud] pero aunque ponga el valor a manualmente seguirá siendo longitud **.**__**.**

Este es todo el código del programa para que lo puedan probar:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h> 

using namespace std;

void rellenar_arr(int* arr, int arr_longtd, int max_random_number);
void mostrar_arr(int* arr, int arr_longtd);
int arr_all_sum(int* arr, int arr_longtd);

int main()
{
    int longitud;
    cout<<"Ingresa la longitud > ";
    cin>>longitud;

    int* array = new int[10];

    rellenar_arr(array, longitud, 20);
    mostrar_arr(array, longitud);

    cout<<" > "<<arr_all_sum(array, longitud);
    
    delete[] array;
    return 0;
}

void rellenar_arr(int* arr, int arr_longtd, int max_random_number)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arr_longtd; i++)
    {
        *(arr+i) = 1 + rand() % max_random_number;
    }
}

void mostrar_arr(int* arr, int arr_longtd)
{
    cout<<"[ ";
    for (int i = 0; i < arr_longtd; i++)
    {
        cout<<*(arr+i)<<" ";
    }
    cout<<"]";
}

int arr_all_sum(int* arr, int arr_longtd)
{
    int suma = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr_longtd; i++)
    {
        suma += *(arr+i);
    }

    return suma;
}
```

Comment: El código es correcto y debería funcionar. ¿Qué IDE o compilador estás usando?

Comment: Uso el compilador WinGW

Comment: qué versión? No será una antigua?

Comment: Te puse todo el código, prueba a ver si te funciona

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer tu programa funciona correctamente, solo que necesitas un "pausador (getch() o system("pause")), debido a que un programa CLI sin aquello se cierra muy rapido.

Answer (score 0):

Fíjate que aunque pides la longitud del array **siempre** creas un array de exactamente 10 elementos

```
int* array = new int[10];
```

Si te da por introducir un tamaño mayor, como posteriormente asumes que en el array van a entrar más elementos, inevitablemente acabarás escribiendo fuera de los límites del array.

Es preferible que el array tenga el tamaño esperado

```
int* array = new int[longitud];
```

Aparte de eso, si quieres que el programa sea aleatorio de verdad, deberías inicializar la semilla del generador de números alearorios

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    // ...
}
```

Claro que, por otro lado, `rand()` es una utilidad propia de C, antigua y desfasada que presenta varios problemas tanto de seguridad como de aleatoriedad. Ya que estás en C++ es preferible usar la librería `random`, la cual está disponible desde C++11:

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 mt(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(1, max_random_number);

for( int i=0; i<arr_longtd; i++ )
{
    std::cout << dist(mt) << '\n';
}
```

Su uso, aunque extraño al principio, tiene su explicación:

- `random_device` es un generador de números pseudoaleatorios no determinista. No necesita semilla inicial pero, en cambio, es bastante lento. Se usa para generar la semilla que utilizaremos para inicializar otro generador más rápido
- `mt19937` es un generador pseudoaleatorio basado en Mersenne Twister.
- `uniform_int_distribution<>` es una clase que nos genera una distribución perfectamente uniforme de números en el rango que le digamos.